# Upvoting during review

Tags: discussion, review

Basically, should I up vote if I think it is a good question/answer in the Late Answers and First Posts review queues?

Answer (score 10):

I just want to go further than [muru's answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17031/527764) and say, if you think it is an upvotable post, or you can edit it to be one yourself, then *please do upvote it* . I feel that I see far too many **No Action Needed** reviews on posts, answers particularly, that deserve an upvote (or a downvote, or indeed a flag, or that obviously need editing). It's very rare I click the <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> button - almost always you can do something with the post IMHO. If it's a good answer (I know it's hard to verify) to an unanswered question then please don't let it get past you without an upvote.

Answer (score 9):

If you would have upvoted otherwise, yes. Voting, up or down, is one of the actions that are sufficient to complete your review of that post.